# Read multiple .wav file from computer and merge them to numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, wav

I need to read multiple `wav` files into separate numpy arrays, then merge the numpy arrays into one and save it as a `wav` file.

How do I do that?

Comment: I guess you want to concatenate arrays with the [numpy.concatenate()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) function.

Comment: First thanks tif for answer me....second Yes i want to concatenate them but i think first i read those numpy arrays form computer...isn't i

Comment: Use scipy to read/write the `wav` data https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html

Comment: @AbdulRafay by merging do you mean 1) mixing them or 2) adding one sound after another?

Comment: @Basj i need to mege them one after the other

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution:

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read, write
import numpy as np

fs, x = read('test1.wav')
f2, y = read('test2.wav')

#z = x + y                    # this is to "mix" the 2 sounds, probably not what you want
z = np.concatenate((x, y))    # this will add the sounds one after another

write('out.wav', fs, z)
```

When doing `x + y`, if the 2 arrays don't have the same length, you need to zero-pad the shortest array, so that they finally have to same length before summing them.

Comment: Should i put all my .wav files to the folder where my .py file exist to ream them...actually i am using anaconda for python?

Comment: 1st question: yes. 2nd question: you have to use a loop for 200 files

Comment: Sorry I have no time to continue so I won't be able to answer on further questions. Just a few hints: try first with 2 files, then 3 files, and once it works, use `import glob` `for f in glob.glob('*.wav'):`, it will loop on all sound files in the folder. Search SackOverflow questions about looping on files with Python for further help. Best of luck for your project! You can "accept" this answer with the tick mark if it helped ;)